# Плавное появление участков блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Необходимо реализовать плавное появление "скрытых" участков. Что бы было понятнее, привожу пример из дизайна, по наведению на блок он должен как бы "выезжать" вперед, т.е. скрытая часть должна плавно появляться над всеми блоками.

[image]

Есть ли уже написанные скрипты для таких целей? Писать с нуля получается накладно, нужно учитывать наложения уголков от соседних блоков.

Я не прошу написать решение, но хочу услышать идеи на этот счёт. Спасибо!

ЗЫ: отображение сделал через изменение z-index, но выглядит не красиво - картинка резко дёргается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#block').css('opacity', 0).hide();
$('.element').hover(
    function(){
        $('#block').show().animate({'opacity': 1}, 300);
    }, function(){
        $('#block').animate({'opacity': 0}, 300, function(){$(this).hide();});
    }
);
```

Полагаю, вы искали что-то такое?

Comment: Это полностью скрывает блоки, а у меня они все должны быть видны. Нужно как-то плавно менять слои местами.

Comment: Тогда на уровне идеи: создавать клон блока, отображать его в том же месте, что и оригинал, но с z-index + 100 и плавно менять его прозрачность. По окончании анимации удалить оригинал. Или у вас все блоки находятся по одинаковым координатам?

Comment: Блоки находятся на разных координатах, фиксированных, как в предоставленном в вопросе дизайне... Спасибо за идею, очень интересно :) Может из этого что-то и получится!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужно чтобы блок при наведении на него плавно вылезал из под другого блока вперед, так чтоб был виден контент. Html разметка не меняеется, вам нужно присваивать новое значение z-index, чтоб он выходил вперед и чтобы он не сразу выпрыгивал, а делал это плавно. Если все правильно, тогда вам можно использовать jquery ui эффект [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/). Он позволяет плавно менять класс элементам, например класс с z-index:1 на класс с z-index:99, в настройках можно выбрать любой визуальный эффект или анимацию.

Comment: С z-index такие манипуляции не проходят... Сейчас с animate ковыряюсь, может чего получится... :)

Comment: посмотри здесь пример, блоки выезжают по клику http://pastehtml.com/view/b2hu0yfxw.html

Comment: В код не вникал, но там по всей видимости сделано по идее, предложенной @ling.  
Уже решена проблема, спасибо за помощь :)